# Erro "[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event"

Tags: javascript

quando tento passar o valor de um select para uma função onChange, ao clicar no botao ele da o seguinte erro no console:

[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.

**CODIGO DO ERRO (pagina onde sao buscados os dados)**

```
<?php
//Conectando ao banco de dados
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "tcc");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());

//Consultando banco de dados
$qryLista = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM postagens");    
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryLista)){
 ?>
<table id='tabela'>
<tr>
<td><?= $r['id'] ?></td>
<td><?= $r['nome'] ?></td>
<td><?= $r['rua'] ?></td>
<td><?= $r['bairro'] ?></td>
<td><?= $r['telefone'] ?></td>
<td><?= $r['descricao'] ?></td>     
<td>
<select id='sel1'>
<option value='status'><?= $r['status'] ?></option>
<option value='pendente'>Pendente</option>
<option value='recolhido'>Recolhido</option>
</select></td>
</table>

<?php 
    }


?>
```

**trecho pagina onde esta a função javascript**

```
<script src="source\jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>



$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sel1').on('change', function () {
         var selecionado = $(this).val(); 
       var selecionado_id = $(this).attr('data-id'); 
        $.ajax({
           data: "id=18&selecionado=recolhido",
          type: 'post',
          url: 'status.php',
      });
  });


</script>
<script>
```

//FUNÇAO QUE DA REFRESH NA PAGINA

```
        function load() {
             $("#tabela").load("getdados.php", null, function () { 
                    $(".loading-div").hide(); 
                });
        };
        $(document).ready(function () {
            load();
            setInterval(function () {
                load();
            }, 8000);
        });
    </script>
    </head>
        Bem vindo
        <?php echo $nome;?> <p>
        <?php echo $email;?><p>
        <a href="sair.php">Sair</a></p>
    <body>

    <div class ="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
   <tr>
  <td>id</td>
  <td>nome</td>
  <td>rua</td>
  <td>bairro</td>
  <td>telefone</td>
  <td>materiais</td>
  <td>Status</td>
</tr>
<tbody id="tabela">

</tbody>
```

Comment: ja esta editado

Comment: Isto não é um erro, é uma série de checagens que esta sendo implementado nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do Chrome e Chromium, são testes de performance geralmente, vou procurar o link da Google que cita isto e te mando.

Answer (score 1):

Há vários erros em seus códigos.

Primeiro você está tentando acessar o `select` por um seletor do tipo `class` sendo que o mesmo não foi atribuído no `select`, há dois jeitos de resolver esse problema já que você definiu um `id`.

Você pode atribuir uma `class` no `select`

```
<select id='sel1' class='sel1'>
```

Ou acessar o `select` pelo seletor `id` alterando a linha do javascript:

```
$('.sel1').on('change', function () {
```

Por:

```
$('#sel1').on('change', function () {
```

Outro erro é que você está tentando recuperar um atributo que seu `select` não possui que é o `data-id`.

```
var selecionado_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

Para corrigir você deve atribuir ele.

```
<select id='sel1' class='sel1' data-id='<?= $r['id'] ?>'>
```

Para saber mais sobre `seletores do jQuery`, leia o artigo [Entendendo os seletores do jQuery](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/entendendo-os-seletores-do-jquery) escrito por **Thiago Belem**

Answer (score 0):

Esta mensagem trata de uma análise do Chrome/Chromium acerca das boas práticas de programação com relação à performance da página. mais especificadamente sobre lag de scroll ou code-blocking.

Na maioria dos casos se refere ao tratamento da auditoria de modo passivo de determinados eventos disparados no Listening.

Segue uma explanação: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

Contém links de páginas teste para você entender melhor os comportamentos apontados.

Espero ter ajudado.

PLUS: Teste do Ligthhouse podem te ajudar com apontamentos das soluções.